# Add follow camera in gltf model

Tags: babylonjs

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas");

  var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);

  createScene = function () {
    var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);

    var camera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera(
      "camera1",
      new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 5, -10),
      scene
    );

    // Targeting the camera to scene origin
    camera.setTarget(new BABYLON.Vector3.Zero());

    // Attaching the camera to canvas
    camera.attachControl(canvas, true);

    var light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight(
      "light1",
      new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0),
      scene
    );

    //create a built-in "sphere" shape; its constructor takes 6 params: name, segment, diameter, scene, updatable, sideOrientation
    var sphere = new BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("Sphere", 16, 2, scene);

    // Move the Sphere upward meanse in y axis
    sphere.position.y = 1;

    var inputMap = {};
    // This sceneloader is for loading gltf models it constructor takes : location, name, scene
    var character = new BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh(
      "",
      "./assets/undercover_cop_-_animated/",
      "scene.gltf",
      scene,
      async function (newMeshes, particleSystems, skeletons, animationGroups) {
        try {
          var dude = newMeshes[0];
          var animations = animationGroups;
          console.log(animations);

          var idleRange = animations[2];
          var walkRange = animations[0];
          var breathingIdleRange = animations[1];

          animations[0].stop();

          dude.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(1.5, 1, 0);
          scene.actionManager = new BABYLON.ActionManager(scene);
          scene.actionManager.registerAction(
            new BABYLON.ExecuteCodeAction(
              BABYLON.ActionManager.OnKeyDownTrigger,
              function (evt) {
                inputMap[evt.sourceEvent.key] =
                  evt.sourceEvent.type == "keydown";
              }
            )
          );
          scene.actionManager.registerAction(
            new BABYLON.ExecuteCodeAction(
              BABYLON.ActionManager.OnKeyUpTrigger,
              function (evt) {
                inputMap[evt.sourceEvent.key] =
                  evt.sourceEvent.type == "keydown";
              }
            )
          );
          scene.onBeforeRenderObservable.add(() => {
            if (inputMap["ArrowUp"]) {
              dude.position.z += 0.1;
              animations[0].play();
            }
            if (inputMap["ArrowLeft"]) {
              dude.position.x -= 0.1;
              animations[0].play();
              dude.rotation.y -= 90;
            }
            if (inputMap["ArrowDown"]) {
              dude.position.z -= 0.1;
              animations[0].play();
              dude.rotation.y += 180;
            }
            if (inputMap["ArrowRight"]) {
              dude.position.x += 0.1;
              animations[0].play();
              dude.rotation.y += 90;
            }

            //Adding follow Camera
          });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      }
    );

    console.log(character);
    // create a built-in "ground" shape;
    var ground = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateGround("ground1", 20, 20, 10, scene);

    // To add the texture
    var groundTexture = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("grounfTexture", scene);
    // Give the location of texture
    groundTexture.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture(
      "./assets/ground_texture.jpg",
      scene
    );

    ground.material = groundTexture;

    return scene;
  };

  var scene = createScene();

  //   This is run render Loop
  engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
    scene.render();
  });

  window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    engine.resize();
  });

  var animationBlending = function* (toAnim, fromAnim) {
    let currentWeight = 1;
    let newWeight = 0;

    toAnim.play(true);

    while (newWeight < 1) {
      newWeight += 0.01;
      currentWeight -= 0.01;
      toAnim.setWeightForAllAnimatables(newWeight);
      fromAnim.setWeightForAllAnimatables(currentWeight);
      yield;
    }
  };
});
```

I want to add the following camera which is attached to gltf character when I move the character camera should follow the character and also follow the camera be the active camera.
I tried it using follow camera inside gltf import mesh inside the loader. By this is started following but can't able to see gltf avatar there.

Comment: May set the camera position relative to your character position when you update it in the render loop or setting the mesh of it as the parent of the camera could work also. Some of the cameras have functions that can point to a given direction. Dependet on how you want to achive it will may require some 3d math